# Execute parameterized JMX file from bat files simultaneously

Tags: batch-file, jmeter, jmx

I have several testcases, which are based on the same `jmx` file with different parameterization. Testcases could be executed with separated `.bat` files. These files look like this:

```
C:\jmeter5\bin\jmeter.bat -t ../config/main/testsuite.jmx -q ../config/main/prop1.properties -JParam1=TRUE -JParam2=FALSE
```

These testcases should be executed parallelly, so I try to execute all these testcases simultaneously.

Comment: You could consider using the `Start` command, with your `.bat` files possibly through `cmd.exe`. I'm not providing any other guesses though, your question is incomplete, it doesn't show us the actual code you've ran, explained what happenened when you did so, or showed what you've tried yourself in rectifying a specific issue. In fact it appears that you just want us to tell you how to do your work. You are not new to this site, and should not need this to be explained to you; please try harder.

Comment: @Compo : Sorry, to be more specific I just want to open and execute these simultaneously without opening as many standalone JMeter windows as many testcases I have. At this time bat files with above content open more JMeter windows, so testcases can be executed in different JMeter instances.

Comment: In `22` hours you have been unable to make any attempt to post an on topic question. Please retake the [tour] and fully read [ask]. After you have done so, please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56444734/edit) to include a properly formatted [mcve] of the code and environment in order for us to help you with a specific issue it is exhibiting.